# Quora search result paging issue by using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, quora

I am using selenium to Login and Search keywords on Quora.Everything is working fine and i have been able to search keyword and get result of the first page.However, i am unable to fetch next page result. I have found the tokens of the next page on site naming **min_seq** on site.However, when i fetched page using selenium the html element which contains that token not present in response. Here is my code of search keyword.

```
    String term = "protein";
    String searchUrl = "https://www.quora.com/search?q=%s";
    String Xport = System.getProperty("lmportal.xvfb.id", ":1");
    final File firefoxPath = new File(System.getProperty("lmportal.deploy.firefox.path",
            "/home/infoobjects/firefox/firefox"));
    FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
    firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", Xport);
    // Start Firefox driver
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, null);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.quora.com/");
    String str = driver.getPageSource();
    System.out.println("str-->"+str);
    WebElement emailElement = driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
    emailElement.sendKeys("<email id>");
    WebElement passwd = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
    passwd.sendKeys("<password>");        
    passwd.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    // get html page after login to selenium
    str = driver.getPageSource(); 
    url = String.format(searchUrl, term);
    driver.get(url);
    str = driver.getPageSource();
    HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();        
    //next page url
    NEXT_URL = node.getElementsByName("body", true)[0].getElementsByName("script", true)[0].getAttributeByName("src");
    System.out.println(NEXT_URL);
```

In this case NEXT_URL giving null.This is because there is no script tag inside body tag into cleaned html.

Any suggestion would be helpful for finding next page of the search results from Quora